# Are Parse id's protected against containing offensive words?

Tags: parse-platform

Are [Parse](http://parse.com/) id's G rated, or do I need to worry about one containing the f-bomb? They don't seem to be base 64, but I don't know any way to tell if they're http://hashids.org/ or something.

Comment: What does g rated mean? Never heard that phrase before.

Comment: Just out of interest. Why are you asking? There may be an alternative that can get you around the problem.

Comment: I need something to put in a web address that uniquely identifies a row in Parse.

Comment: In that case. If you cannot guarantee that the parse object id is safe then you could always generate your own unique id and put it in a separate column. You could even make it easier to reference/remember. Or even create a parse http request function to runs. Query based on the input. Etc...

Comment: Yes, I can just add a column with a hashid, but then I have to guarantee uniqueness of the input to hashid and add that dependency to my code. If the Parse id's are safe, I have fewer moving parts.

Comment: Yes. That's true. Probably the best people to ask would be parse. They have a support forum which the staff sometimes answer. I thinks it's a google community thing now actually. You could use a UUID that would remove the need for checking for uniqueness. Whilst it is possible to get duplicate values it's probability of happening is pretty much zero because of the huge number of UUIDs available. Heh, even iPhones use UUIDs. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hector Ramos of Parse says in [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/wKTAccMB_5g) that they're automatically generated.

Everyone downplays the likelihood of unfortunate id's — except the person in a chat I frequent (unnamed to protect their employer's privacy) who in their words "got bit by the ass code".